# Draw rect according to json array?

Tags: jquery, json, d3.js, javascript

I find d3js very interesting.So I thought may be I should give it a shot.I am fairly new to this framework and need some assistance
I have a **json file**.This is how it goes--:

```
            ["2511a51", [["mumbai",1,6], ["Baroda",2,7]]]
            ["2882bd9", [["mumbai",3,8], ["chennai", 2,9]]]
            ["1d3e1a2", [["mumbai",0,3],["Baroda",2,6], ["Delhi",7,1]]]
            ["1882b41", [["mumbai",10,9]]]
            ["1d4ffd8", [["chennai",2,5], ["mumbai", 5,9], ["Delhi",8,8]]]
```

Here,

- 2511a51 is session id(ignore)
- **Mumbai,baroda,chennai and delhi !!!** are indian cities.
- *Mumbai=draw red rectangle, baroda=brown rectangle ,chennai=green rectangle,delhi=blue rectangle*

What I want is,if a json row has a and b -->then their respective colored rectangle should be drawn keeping c and d empty.So for this entire array,I get the below output. 
As the image goes,

- 5 session id`s means 5 rows.
- first and second rows includes two rectangles,third and fifth row have 3 rectangle and 4th row have 1 rectangle with every city having their respective colour and column
- Based on second value(ex.1 and 6 for 1st row)-->**their colour intensity will be depended!!!more the number,darker the colour**!!!

I want to code my javascript in such a way that I get this---:
[image: Outout of array!!!]

[MY fiddle--not working](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/EdjbH/)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>demo-staticArray!!!</title>

</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var SVG = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("class","stage")
            .attr("width",800)
            .attr("height",600)
            .style("background-color", "beige")
            .style("margin-left","200");

    var array=  ["2511a51", [["a",1], ["b",2]]]
            ["2882bd9", [["a",3], ["c", 2]]]
            ["1d3e1a2", [["a",0],["b",2], ["d",7]]]
            ["1882b41", [["a",10]]]
            ["1d4ffd8", [["c",2], ["b", 5], ["d",8]]]

    var RECT= SVG.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", 30)
            .attr("height", 10)
            .style("fill","red");//how do I provide conditions for fill-->a=red,b=brown,c=green,d=blue
    //how do I manage them such that they are arranged in a manner shown in the image.
    //I am unable to move ahead of this!!!!I am facing problem in iterations and conditions

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If possible,please give a small working sample!!!

Comment: Typically, you should provide a jsfiddle for this kind of 'mission'...

Comment: yes ,I agree but i dont know how to add d3.js script in it??

Comment: 5 min!!!I am putting up the fiddle

Comment: (external sources on the left)

Comment: d3.js is also in "Framework and extensions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 2 :  every time you are working with `selects` in d3 you are mapping data to your UI elements and their properties. in most of the cases you are doing it this way

```
 ... select('rect').data(myData)
```

then you need to actually map properties of items in your data set to the properties of UI elements, you are doing it providing functions which do the mapping , ie

```
  var myData = [{x:0, y:0 } , { x: 100 , y : 100 }]
  // we mapped our data to rect elements on svg canvas 
  // and created new rect elements for data items which didnt have it before
  // now we have two elements in total as myData had 2 elements
  var rect = svg.select('rect').data(myData).enter()

  // now each rect has x attribute equals to 'x' property of data item
  rect.attr('x', function(d) { return d.x } )

  // and the same for y attribute and 'y' property
  rect.attr('y', function(d) { return d.y } )

  // now if you also set height and width properties of UI elements 
  // you will see two rectangulars
  rect.attr('width', 50).attr('height', 50)


  // now you can rewrite your previos lines like that
  var xScale = function(d) { return d.x }
  rect.attr('x', xScale)
```

And now it is clear that if you have more complicated way of figuring out your X coordinate on the canvas than just your data item property, you will have more complicated function than current `xScale`

Now recalling school course of geometry we can do transformation from one scale to another , for instance

```
  var xScale = function(d) { return 50 + d.x * 100 }
```

which means that if d.x equals to 1 , function will return 150 , for 2 it would be 250 etc

And last step , in order to avoid figuring out on your own how to create this scale function ,you can use built in d3 features , links to which I put in the end of the answer, for instance

```
   var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
           .domain([0, 10]).range([50, 550])
```

UPDATED: fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EdjbH/5/

NOTES: I slightly changed  your source data in order for it to make more sense to d3. Take a look at how color is generated, you will need to build your own palete as for instance gines capote recomended. In order to draw axises you can use d3 built in functions.

You need to do 3 things

- to create x-axis and y-axis scales based on your domain
- add `.attr('x', function(d){ return xAxis(d[0]) })` and `.attr('y', function(d){ return yAxis(d[1]) })` to your code generating RECT
- fill also accept function , and it make sense to create scale to use here as well, would be something like `.style('fill', function(d) { return colorScale(d[0]]) })`

Also because in fact you have array of array you need to change `.data(data)` to `.data(function(d){ return d[1] })`

Alternatively you can code you scales by hand like

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("class","stage")
        .attr("width",800)
        .attr("height",600)
        .style("background-color", "beige");

var data=  [{ key :"2511a51", values : [["a",1], ["b",2]] },
         { key :"2882bd9", values : [["a",3], ["c", 2]]},
         { key: "1d3e1a2", values : [["a",0],["b",2], ["d",7]] },
         { key :"1882b41", values : [["a",10]] },
         { key :"1d4ffd8", values : [["c",2], ["b", 5], ["d",8]]}];

var width  = 30, padding = 10, height = 10  

var   code = function (c) {return c.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) }
, xScale = function (d) { return (width + 2*padding) * code(d[0]) }
, yScale = function (d) { return (height + 2 * padding) * d[1] }            
, color = d3.scale.category20() // replace with your palete
, cScale = function(d) { return color(code(d[0])) }

var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g")

var rects= g.selectAll("rect.colored")
        .data(function(d){ return d.values })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr('class','colored')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr('x', xScale )
        .attr('y', yScale )
        .style('fill',  cScale);
```

check this references

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category10

Comment: So foolish of me,I just noticed it right now!!!
If there are 5 session id`s in json then there should be five rows,Thats what the image shows above.And we done wrong alignment!!!Our output has some 8 rows,I noticed it very late,i am sorry
---2 Problem---there is unnecessary gap left between rows.I am right now trying to understand your code and tweaking it a bit.

Comment: I have updated my question,please have a look at it!!!
The array values have been changed and one more functionality is to be  added---i.e based on the second value -- [["parties", 8,2]]]--->so based on value 2,the color should be a little dim,if it was more than 5 ,than it should be a little more intense!!!

Comment: I have understood most of your code,but i am not able to understand this part--->var code = function (c) {return c.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) } 

I tried to tweak a little with this part,but wasnt useful!!!my array
have now have mumbai,baroda,chennai,delhi instead of delhi,So chartcode wont work with it!!!Some ideas?
This project is little difficult than what i thought!!!

Comment: I think Table is the only suggestion!!!
I have made a sample table-->http://jsfiddle.net/
--how can you put rectangles in to it???

This is how my crude json is----->http://jsfiddle.net/rjZxJ/
I have simplified it for understanding purpose.Please replace a,b,c,d by cities!!!

Comment: @MESSIAH so you have array of sessions and number of session in the list define row in the table. Each session has array of points, specifying city and two numbers, city defines column, first number is ignored and second number define color saturation, is it right?

Comment: BANG!!!!exactly..you got the point...In reality my array looks like this ----->
jsfiddle.net/rjZxJ

I think charcodeat method is not suitable,table would be perfect..the problem is cant go to the next level when I am stuck.

Comment: if possible...dont go by the key:value method because my orignal array is more like http://jsfiddle.net/rjZxJ/
------------
parsed version---->http://jsfiddle.net/9VyGM/

Comment: @MESSIAH Read this article , it has all the things you need to build table, https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#more-table-madness-sorting-prettifying-and-adding-columns

Comment: I know how to build up a table!!!but the problem comes when i want to put a rectangle in it!!!

Comment: Read the article. you dont need rectangles. your table cell is rectangle already, just apply styles for it

Comment: @MESSIAH To remove spaces, replace `width +2 * padding` with just `width`. CharCodeAt is used to get number for string, you can create just object like ` obj = { 'a' : 1 , 'b' :2 } ` and use it instead `obj['a']`

Comment: @MESSIAH Link that I gave you is the same D3.js library, it explains how to build table 90 percent like you have.

Comment: :yes, read that but still vague about it ,i am totally drained off now,have been playing with it for quite a while now!!!i have to sumbit it tommorow,too less time and lot of things to do!i know it sounds silly but just get me through the table or any other idea would do!!!I am still in to learning stages of this library and  got to learn lot of things today ,went through some tutorials,if possible a small sample fiddle would be great!just one last favour!!plzz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32437/discussion-between-messiah-and-vittore)

Comment: @MESSIAH Dude you are not even trying, may be you choose wrong area to work in ? Check fiddle, code almost entirely from the article i sent you , just couple of line changed. http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/EdjbH/12/

Comment: thanx vittore ,the project is over now...but i am still not able to understand your grtColumn cell part...

Comment: @MESSIAH what exactly is unclear? just create new questions with details as it is unrelated to d3.

Comment: what is get column cells doing?

Comment: @MESSIAH getting cell for column from array

Comment: ret = arr[i][0] == col ? arr[i] : ret;
I understand shorthands but can you guide me with this line...i am not sure what is it actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
var color = new Array();
color[0]="red";
color[1]="blue";
```

And then:

```
.style("fill", function(f) { ... return color[1] }
```

the ... means if json has row a or b or whatever

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a good example](http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271) which is close to what you are looking for on [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271).